# Is there any record on this specific variant of the character 選?

Tags: characters, traditional-characters, classical-chinese

The below variant of the Traditional character 選 comes from an old book of 20th-century Vietnam. I personally cannot find any source that acknowledges this variant. I'm also pretty sure that Unicode doesn't have this glyph.

[image: 選]

In addition, since this variant is likely Vietnamese-made, I hope to know about any source that records Vietnamese-varied Chinese characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have searched these two websites and no one matches this character. http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/fra/fra04185.htm and http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/search.jsp?q=%E9%81%B8&x=58&y=10&stype=3 .

Comment: Please tell us what book and which page this character is from, so that we could offer more helps. It's better if you put the picture of the entire page :)

Comment: @TravisHu These are cover pages of the book: https://leminhkhai.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/hoidinh1.jpg?w=736 . All credits go to the blog https://leminhkhai.wordpress.com .

Comment: Now I am pretty sure about this word. It's one of 選's variant. This book is called 《會庭文選》. There are three different versions of the cover of this book: 1. http://lib.nomfoundation.org/collection/1/volume/980/ which is the same as you provided, in 1865; 2. http://lib.nomfoundation.org/collection/1/volume/1152/ , in 1892; 3. http://lib.nomfoundation.org/collection/1/volume/980/ , in 1893.

Comment: @TravisHu So, was this variant an actual one or just a printing one? By the way, your third link is as same as the first one.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure which one it belongs to... The 3rd link should be http://lib.nomfoundation.org/collection/1/volume/978/ in 1898. Sorry for the wrong link AND THE WRONG YEAR.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Vietnamese used Chinese characters a long time ago, perhaps only in learned circles. They also created their own "Chinese" characters, which were not known in China.

I had a similar case of a character I could not find. I downloaded some fonts called HAN NOM A.ttf and HAN NOM B.ttf, then I could write the character, but I can't remember what it was now.

Maybe you can get some leads here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%E1%BB%AF_N%C3%B4m

Comment: I've known about Chữ Nôm. It was indeed made by the Vietnamese to replace Classical Chinese characters. Chữ Nôm consists of characters directly from Classical Chinese, and characters that are made up. I have a dictionary of Chữ Nôm, so I'm pretty sure that Chữ Nôm had taken 選 directly from Chinese. Moreover, Unicode seems to already code all Chữ Nôm characters, so that variant is probably not a Chữ Nôm character.

Answer (score 1):

The component is Vietnam-specific. See https://hc.jsecs.org/irg/ws2017/app/index.php?id=00202:

[image]

---

**References:**

- Tự Điển Chữ Nôm Dẫn Giải, *Nguyễn Quang Hồng* / 阮光宏《字典字喃引解》

Comment: Actually, consider this component as an independent character, Unicode currently cite its sources all of which are not from Vietnam (hope they change it soon). By the way, U+209C6 (in the picture) is indeed Vietnamese. Back to the point, the variant of 選 has yet seemed to be classified so far.